Unexplainable noise in STL of clean, seasonal data
I am encountering unexplained noise in the residual component after STL decomposition.
I use this dataset taken from NAB's benchmark. It is a periodic (daily) timeseries, with no noise or anomalies.
Then, I perform STL to decompose the residual but getting unexpected noise.
The residual component is too noisy, considering the fact that the data is very clean. See below:

Here is the notebook with the results.
Is this noise expected for some reason?

The noise is on the scale of 1e-12, which is very small, and probably a result of floating point errors.

@Oxbowerce, makes sense thank you
